# tell me about parameter q in dismax query parser (solr)

Tags: java, xml, solr

I am trying to use dis-max query parser (http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=name&qt=defType=dismax)

So can you plz tell me that what is parameter q... I mean what value I pass to it ....

coz the above syntax gives an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the actual search string you want to `q`

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler?action=show&redirect=StandardRequestHandler#q

and

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#Examples

Comment: but how can i search through dismax query,with boost function

Comment: for boost function add *bf=text^2* where text is the field which is to be boosted